# Created custom theme in magento 2.1 but parent name on backend is not showing up

Tags: magento2, admin, theme

I created one custome theme but parent name on backend is not showing up.
here is the code,

> Theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>m2-theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/PorthosHome_Homepage.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

> Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "Iverve/m2-theme",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "Iverve/m2-theme": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

> Registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Iverve/m2-theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

and added jpg file in the media folder.

I am getting this in the backend

[image]

Comment: have you tried deploying the static content ? php magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme {vendorName}/myTheme2

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the require `"magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*"` in `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "Iverve/m2-theme",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```